# sapui5 OData.V4.oDataModel with Teiid 11.2 / Wildfly

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use SAPUI5 in a SPA to display data from a TEIID/Wildfly ODataV4 service. When SAPUI5 ODATA V4 data model is bound to the service, I run into several errors. I thereby connect via proxy (grunt-connect-proxy2) to the odata service. Basic Auth works. The metadata file above the marked service folder in the attached image (screenshot1) is the actual metadata file of the service which, as you can see, is loaded correctly. So no CORS issue or authorization issue.

Screenshot1

[image: Screenshot1]

The issue seems to be related to an CSRF Token request as far as I understand. Seems that Teiid/Wildfly is not answering the CSRF Token fetch request. Is there a way to configure Wildfly to answer the request or alternatively a way to disable CSRF requests for the odata V4 model? I have seen such an option in the constructor of the odata V2 model. How could a working configuration look like?

The following is a screenshot from the browser log:

I observed a further issue, from which I do not know if it is related to the previous one (there is also a X-CSRF-Token: Fetch involved), or if a have something more missing somewhere. The second issue happens when I use an aggregation binding to bind a odata collection to a sapui5 list. The response looks like

> Request URL: http://localhost:9001/odata4/svc/my_nutri_diary/$batch
>   Request Method: POST Status Code: 406 Not Acceptable Remote Address:
>   [::1]:9001 Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade Response
>   Headersview source access-control-allow-credentials: true
>   access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:9001 cache-control:
>   no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate connection: close
>   content-encoding: gzip content-length: 125 content-type:
>   application/json;odata.metadata=minimal date: Mon, 12 Nov 2018
>   20:04:30 GMT expires: 0 odata-version: 4.0 pragma: no-cache server:
>   WildFly/11 x-powered-by: Undertow/1 Request Headersview source Accept:
>   multipart/mixed Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: de
>   Authorization: Basic SU1TVXNlcjpJTVM0Zm9ydW0l Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 329 Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>   boundary=batch_id-1542053070786-11 Cookie: sidebar_collapsed=false;
>   cycle_analytics_help_dismissed=1;
>   __utmz=111872281.1539128843.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=111872281.767670437.1539128843.1541866362.1541870562.42 DNT: 1 Host: localhost:9001 MIME-Version: 1.0 OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
>   OData-Version: 4.0 Origin: http://localhost:9001 Referer:
>   http://localhost:9001/ User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS
>   11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1 X-CSRF-Token: Fetch
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Request Payload
>   --batch_id-1542053070786-11 Content-Type:application/http Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary GET Profile?$skip=0&$top=100 HTTP/1.1
>   Accept:application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=true
>   Accept-Language:de
>   Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8;IEEE754Compatible=true
>   --batch_id-1542053070786-11--

Thanks for your advice!

Best regards,
 Christoph

Further note regarding search for a workaround: As I am currently searching for a workaround to be able to use the odata.v4 model, I found the following blog post:

https://blogs.sap.com/2015/08/05/disable-csrf-token-for-odata-calls-using-sap-netweaver-gateway/

However, the approach does not seem to work for the odata.v4 model as it has a different interface. There is no setHeaders() function to set custom headers on the  datamodel. I therefore tried to set the header up via

$.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'X'}});

Unfortunately, this also does not work. If someone has the odata.v4 Model running with TEIID or Olingo v4 it would be great if he could give me a feedback on how he had worked around this issue.